# Rails server & React client: CORS issues despite same origin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, axios, cors

- I have a Rails API server with `rack-cors` that allow access from `localhost` and `server` (Docker container name, to be accessed from a Node.js server, works fine with it).
- When I run any request to my server directly from my browser in `localhost`, it works perfectly.
- When I make a request with `axios.get()` in React (running from `localhost:3000`, my client, to `localhost:3001`, my server), I get the following error from the client console despite the request being well executed on the Rails server side:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3001/items' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Any idea what's wrong and on what side?

```
# config/initializers/cors.rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins 'localhost', 'server' 
    resource '*', headers: :any, methods: %i[get post patch put delete options]
  end
end
```

Comment: ports matter with cors, so you need to add `localhost:3001` or you can [proxy requests](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) locally and not worry about cors until deploying

Comment: Good point, but why I don't find much documentation about specifying the port in the CORS policy?

`localhost:3001` doesn't work though, neither `localhost:*`, only `*` works so far :-/

Comment: Nevermind, it's `localhost:3000` since it's the host of the requester (my client app).

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to the help of @DCTID, I figured out that the port had to be specified in Rails CORS configuration file. Since I want to allow any port from those domains, I put this regular expression (the `http://` prefix is needed):

`origins %r{\Ahttp://(localhost|server)(:\d+)?\z}`